# WCF Rest Application_End

Tags: wcf, rest, global-asax

I have a WCF Rest service and I have added this attributes to service:

```
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
 [ServiceContract]
```

I am not sure which one of the 2 of this statements are correct :

- Application_End from Global.asax will be called everytime a request is completed

or

- Application_End from Global.asax will be called once when the IIS will fire recycle

Can you help me out? I am having trouble understanding so many Application_End in my logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InstanceContextMode.PerCall -- spawns an instance of your service per call. Unlike the standard first in first out approach. If you hit your service with 10 requests at once you should see 10 Application_End events.

Application_End from Global.asax will be called everytime a request is completed

Comment: can you supply official documentation to support you statement?